# Primefaces picklist - java.lang.NullPointerException org.primefaces.component.picklist.PickListRenderer.encodeOptions(PickListRenderer.java:233)

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using picklist with POJO and getting null pointer exception. Can anyone guide me in this

**XHTML(picklist inside dialog)**

```
p:pickList converter="#{pickListConverter}" value="#{rewardsOfferBean.selectedEOffer.members}" var="member" itemLabel="#{member.firstName} #{member.lastName}" itemValue="#{member}" />
```

**POJO**

```
private DualListModel<RewardsMemberAccount> members = new DualListModel<RewardsMemberAccount>(new ArrayList<RewardsMemberAccount>(),new ArrayList<RewardsMemberAccount>());
```

**Bean - RewardsOfferBean**

```
public RewardsOffer getSelectedEOffer() {

        selectedEOffer.setMembers(new DualListModel<RewardsMemberAccount>(service.getAllLoyaltyMembersName(), selectedEOffer.getMembersName()));
        return selectedEOffer;
    }
```

**Exception**

```
 javax.servlet.ServletException


javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:606)
    org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:105)
root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.primefaces.component.picklist.PickListRenderer.encodeOptions(PickListRenderer.java:233)
    org.primefaces.component.picklist.PickListRenderer.encodeList(PickListRenderer.java:203)
    org.primefaces.component.picklist.PickListRenderer.encodeMarkup(PickListRenderer.java:99)
    org.primefaces.component.picklist.PickListRenderer.encodeEnd(PickListRenderer.java:59)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:312)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.renderRow(GridRenderer.java:185)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:129)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
    org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:79)
    org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:66)
    org.primefaces.component.dialog.DialogRenderer.encodeContent(DialogRenderer.java:180)
    org.primefaces.component.dialog.DialogRenderer.encodeMarkup(DialogRenderer.java:109)
    org.primefaces.component.dialog.DialogRenderer.encodeEnd(DialogRenderer.java:47)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1786)
    javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1779)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
    org.primefaces.component.tabview.TabViewRenderer.encodeTabContent(TabViewRenderer.java:307)
    org.primefaces.component.tabview.TabViewRenderer.encodeContents(TabViewRenderer.java:265)
    org.primefaces.component.tabview.TabViewRenderer.encodeMarkup(TabViewRenderer.java:131)
    org.primefaces.component.tabview.TabViewRenderer.encodeEnd(TabViewRenderer.java:71)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:312)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:309)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GroupRenderer.encodeChildren(GroupRenderer.java:105)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:304)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.renderRow(GridRenderer.java:185)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:129)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1779)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:402)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:125)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:105)
```

Comment: Is the `#{pickListConverter}` properly being reached and returning proper values on the `getAsString` method?

Comment: @Xtreme Biker: 
 I checked with debugging, converter is not reachable. Have implemented Converter and added @FacesConverter(value = "pickListConverter") annotation also. Am I missing anything?

Comment: can anyone guide me???

Comment: Do not use `#{pickListConverter}` notation to access the converter by its name. Use either `converter="pickListConverter"` when using its name or `converter="#{pickListConverter}"` if you annotate your converter as a managed bean.